# Does not insert data in mysql

Tags: php, html

I have a form with an input submit. When I click on the submit button it calls a PHP function that updates data in mysql. All is working OK until I add an action in the form. In the action I add the source to the downloading file and when I click the submit button it only downloads the file but does not update data in mysql.

```
<?
include "main.php";

$get->downloadCounter();
?>

<form method="post" id="form-id" action="/script/pages/files/test.rar">
        <input type="submit" value="Download" name="submit" id="download_btn_submit" class="download_btn icon_download_btn">
        </form>



// main.php

<?

include 'db.php';

class getData extends Connection {


    public function downloadCounter() {

            //protect from people getting other files
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $id = $_GET['id'];

            $sql="update scripts set downloads=downloads+1 where id=:id";
            $data = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
            $data->execute(array(':id'=>$id));

            header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    }
}

}

$get = new getData();

?>

// page.php
```

Comment: Because you are posting to a rar file, not your script.

Comment: @gre_gor so what? it downloads file but does not update value in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use the action attribute like that, because in your case the form needs to submit data to your script, not to the .rar file. What you could do is add a hidden input with the path of the file to download:

```
<form method="post" id="form-id">
    <input type="hidden" name="fileToDownload" value="/script/pages/files/test.rar">
    <input type="submit" value="Download" name="submit" id="download_btn_submit" class="download_btn icon_download_btn">
</form>
```

And then in your `main.php`, replace this:

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

with this:

```
header('Location: '.$_POST['fileToDownload']);
```